# UIImage looks different when used in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am having problems with a `png` image, that gets wrong colors on iOS compared to the actual image.

It does not matter how I am using the image, it always gets the wrong colors. I have tried on `UIButton` and `UIImageView` and it gives the same result.

It is a very standard use of a `UIImage`:

```
UIImage* greenButtonImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn_green"];
UIImageView* testView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:greenButtonImg];
[self.view addSubview:testView];
```

The second image is how it looks on iOS and the first button is how it looks on my Mac (Finder and Photoshop):

[image: First button is as the image looks on the Mac, second image is as the image look on iOS]

As you can see the second button has a different green color.
This is happening all over the app where am using this picture. It happens in the Simulator and on a iPhone 5.

What can cause this issue? Can this be caused by settings in Photoshop, where the image was created?

Comment: Check your RGB Profiles in  Photoshop, images can appear different colours across systems if certain profiles are used.

Comment: are you checking it on iOS 7.0???

Comment: @NileshPatel Yes, I was checking it on iOS 7.0.

Comment: Actually Apple introduced the new feature in iOS 7. Called Image Rendering Mode.. You can use image as template.. I have given brief description in answer.. please take a look..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Jeff wrote in a comment it was a problem with the RGB Profiles.

I managed to fix the problem by converting the color profile in Photoshop:

`Edit -> Convert to Profile... -> Set profile to "Apple RGB"`

Comment: I can't until tomorrow :) There is a two day delay to accept your own answers.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 7.0, the image is colored with the toolbar’s `tintColor`.

In iOS 7.0, all subclasses of `UIView` derive their behavior for `tintColor` from the base class.

By default, an image (`UIImage`) is created with `UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic`.

If you have `UIImageRenderingModeAutomatic` set on your image, it will be treated as template or original based on its context.

Certain `UIKit` elements—including navigation bars, tab bars, toolbars, segmented controls—automatically treat their foreground images as templates, although their background images are treated as original.

Other elements—such as image views and web views—treat their images as originals. If you want your image to always be treated as a template regardless of context, set `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate`.

If you want your image to always be treated as original, set `UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal`.

Refer [Template Images](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW7) for more info.

Comment: Thank you for the background info, it helped me to solve the issue that all images I've loaded where displayed in the tintColor!